# BIOS doesn't recognize my M.2 SSD

Tags: ssd, motherboard, bios, nvme

I've decided to upgrade my PC by adding a second M.2 SSD, but my BIOS doesn't recognize it

new [SSD](https://www.ozon.ru/product/240-gb-ssd-disk-wd-original-wds240g2g0b-wds240g2g0b-181916048/)

[Motherboard](https://aliexpress.ru/item/4000120773162.html)

BIOS: American Megatrends

The motherboard contains two M.2 NVME slots and as I understood from the question bellow that if the M.2 fits in the slot then it will work
[Can you connect an M.2 SATA to an M.2 NVMe port?](https://superuser.com/questions/1303299/can-you-connect-an-m-2-sata-to-an-m-2-nvme-port)

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Some older motherboards had M.2 slots but were SATA only and would not work with NVMe drives, The mobo manual should tell you or sometimes they print right next to the slot to let you know what it will take.

Comment: I understand what you mean but in this case, the motherboard isn't old and it is working perfectly with the first NVME stick.

Comment: do you have the sata ports related to the lanes for your M.2 slots empty? usually they share lanes, so you can only use the M.2 if you aren't using the sata ports using those lanes. once again, your mobo manual should say. Also of the three M.2 ports on my current Mobo, only one of them can be bootable (M.2_2).

Comment: Mm.. I’ve been using m.2 nvme and sata hdd together and they were working. Now I’ve added m.2 ssd to the second m.2 port but my bios doesn’t see it at all. I guess I have to change some settings in bios. I tried but couldn’t fix the issue. I even formatted the new ssd to ext4 in a hope that my ubuntu will recognize it - without any success

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t read Russian, so I can’t read any of the specifications you have provided

Comment: Capacity: 240GB
Speed: Solid State Memory
Interface Types: SATA, SATA M.2 NGFF
Form Factor: M.2 x 80mm
Sector Size: 512 / 512e
Sustained Throughput: 545
Electrical Interface: SATA 600 - 6.0Gbps
SSD Type: SLC
SSD Endurance DWPD: Consumer / Value