# M.2 SSD - BIOS - not recognized

Tags: ssd, bios

I've added a second M.2 SSD, but my BIOS doesn't recognize it

new [SSD](https://www.ozon.ru/product/240-gb-ssd-disk-wd-original-wds240g2g0b-wds240g2g0b-181916048/)

[Motherboard](https://aliexpress.ru/item/4000120773162.html)

BIOS: American Megatrends

The motherboard contains two M.2 NVME slots and as I understood from the question bellow that if the M.2 fits in the slot then it will work
[Can you connect an M.2 SATA to an M.2 NVMe port?](https://superuser.com/questions/1303299/can-you-connect-an-m-2-sata-to-an-m-2-nvme-port)

Capacity: 240GB Speed: Solid State Memory Interface Types: SATA, SATA M.2 NGFF Form Factor: M.2 x 80mm Sector Size: 512 / 512e Sustained Throughput: 545 Electrical Interface: SATA 600 - 6.0Gbps SSD Type: SLC SSD Endurance

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Capacity: 240GB Speed: Solid State Memory Interface Types: SATA, SATA M.2 NGFF Form Factor: M.2 x 80mm Sector Size: 512 / 512e Sustained Throughput: 545 Electrical Interface: SATA 600 - 6.0Gbps SSD Type: SLC SSD Endurance

Comment: Check your MB specs to see if it supports SATA, its possible that it does not.  While it fits physically, it may not "fit" electronically.

Comment: M.2 SATA port isnt compatible with M.2 nVME Your product pages are not in english so i can't determine if you purchased a SATA or nVME M.2 drive

Comment: @essjae
ok that's interesting
the two ports are M.2 NVME, 
so as I understood that 
M.2 NVME ports support both types of stick M.2 SATA SSD and M.2 NVME SSD
while M.2 SATA ports support only M.2 SATA sticks

Comment: @Ramhound
the new stick is M.2 SSD

Comment: @nazihhizan - NVMe and SATA m.2 are not compatible with one another.  So what type of m.2 drives does your motherboard support (again I can’t look since you provided product pages that are not in English)