# How can I know if a M.2 PCIe NVME port can be adapted into SATA?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata, storage

I want to buy a notebook (the dell g-15 5510 or the lenovo ideapad 3i) but storage is a big deal to me, and since these machines come with a ssd of 512gb max, I would like to update it with a HDD (more affordable) in the extra slot.

The problem is that both of them come with a extra NVME slot, instead of the sata slot that is necessary to plug in a HDD.

I've researched and saw that there are adpators, but as I suspected there are more problems that can interfere with this adaption.

Can someone please tell me how can I be sure if a computer can have adaption to take a HDD on a NVME slot ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you connect an M.2 SATA to an M.2 NVMe port?](https://superuser.com/questions/1303299/can-you-connect-an-m-2-sata-to-an-m-2-nvme-port)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what does "a HDD (more affordable)" even mean in this context. Are you really referring to 2.5" HDD or are you talking about M.2 SATA SSD? The thing is either way your question doesn't make much sense, as for the former, whether your M.2 slot supports SATA drive hardly matters (in the case of notebook computer), and for the latter, M.2 SATA SSD is often *less* affordable than M.2 NVMe SSD these days (well, unless you are living in some country where pricing are weird / "outdated"...)

Comment: @TomYan seems to be asking if a hard drive (which is more affordable) can be plugged into an NVME slot (M.2?) using an adapter, since M.2 slots can support both "NVME" (PCIe) and SATA interfaces, but not all do.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's my question. A hard driver is more affordable, but they connect using SATA slots. The thing is: I know I can't do the connection directly, but I heard that there are ways of adapting this slot, although I'm not sure if that's really possible.

Comment: of course you will also have the problem that the drive probably doesn't fit inside the laptop! There is rarely any extra space, and the NVME slot space is not big enough to fit a hard drive.

Comment: Oh is it ? That's sad. I had the same procedure on a idepad 330 and I had an adapter that was kinda like a case. I used to install a Hard driver and I use it to this day without any problem.

Comment: Though an external HDD is an extra device to carry, it might be easier to use than trying to fit one into the laptop. A 2 TB external HDD, powered by USB, can be found for ~US$40, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/External-Portable-Shockproof-Laptop-Silver/dp/B0B4KKT5SJ/ref=sr_1_17_sspa (example not rated).

Comment: Thanks for this option, it seems very viable since I'd store mostly files and videos. Since I'm already here, might as well ask: Is there any problem on running programs on a HDD powered by a USB ? Or is it like a normal HDD ? I believe that a USB port wouldn't be as effective as built in Sata ports.