Will Acer aspire 5 A515-51-32U4 support NVMe SSD?
I am having acer aspire 5 A515-51-32U4 laptop with KBL Charmander KL v2.02 motherboard and i3 7130U processor. I have physically checked for the m.2 slot on my motherboard but I am not sure whether it will support NVMe or not. Should I go with m.2 SATA or m.2 NVMe?


Based on the discussion here, it will support NVMe. Since you mentioned you can physically check the motherboard, use this to confirm: https://superuser.com/questions/1303299/can-you-connect-an-m-2-sata-to-an-m-2-nvme-port

You best bet is to check the manufacturer's website, such as Crucial's (https://www.crucial.com/store/advisor)

I'm eyeballing the slot, and it'll support NVMe most likely
Zooming in a little on the slot

There's a single notch there, which looking at wikipedia's page on M.2, corresponds to a M-Key. Its possible this slot would work with a sata drive as well, but its designed to fit an NVMe drive. There's also a few people who  have tried this - this youtube video from Viorel Caia shows the upgrade being done, and there's a few folks who report it works for them
So looking at everything the slot physically and electrically should support a NVMe drive

Is M-key reserved for only NVMe M2 drives? The M.2 x4 suggests PCIe x4 which would suggest NVMe not SATA

.... I missed the great big M.2 x4.  Well, I suspect it might be, and OP really does want to know if they can put a NVMe drive there so... confirmed ?
